# Why do python Subprocess.stdin.write() kill PyQt Gui

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess

I have a PyQt5 app that need to write input for the subprocess to stop.

However it also kills my PyQt5 `Mainwindow`, if input button is used without using subprocess button first.

If i use subprocess button first, and then use input button , with `self.bob.stdin.write("b")` app stays open, but if i press input button first without pressing subprocess button `self.bob.stdin.write("b")` it kills my app and Mainwindow.

So why do `self.bob.stdin.write("b")` kill app ,and how do i stop it from killing my MainWindow, if i press input button first ?

The dilemma can be seen in this test code.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(308, 156)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 121, 71))
        self.Button_2.setObjectName("subprocessButton_2")
        self.Button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 121, 71))
        self.Button_1.setObjectName("inputbutton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.Button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "subprocess"))
        self.Button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "input"))

        self.Button_2.clicked.connect(self.sub)
        self.Button_1.clicked.connect(self.input)

    def sub(self):

        import subprocess
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        self.bob = subprocess.Popen('cmd ',stdin=PIPE, shell=True)

    def input(self):
        self.bob.stdin.write("q")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the minimal necessary example to demonstrate the problem? This makes it easier to find the problem.

Comment: removed few lines, its minimum for app creation, and two pushbuttons functions

If you press the left button, and then right button then its okay.

But if you press left first, then GUI quits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding all your code, here's what I think your code converted into a script does:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# sub button handler
bob = subprocess.Popen('echo',stdin=PIPE, shell=True)

# input button handler
bob.stdin.write(b"text")
```

I'll let you think about what hapens when you don't do step 1.

Comment: yes that is my scripts narrowed down, but problem is, that it is a part of a PyQt Gui, and that is what bob.stdin.write(b"text") kills

Comment: I see , offcause it cant find bob in step two since its in step one.Facepalm 

thx

Comment: You probably get an `AttributeError` when you do `self.bob`. I would say you have a few possibilities here: (1) wrap the function in `try… catch AttributeError`, (2) check at the start of the function for `self.bob` or (3) disable the second button until `self.bob` is available.

Comment: yes i get a AttributeError.

after some testing best option was to disable input button til subprocess button was pressed. thx